# Silverlight, path through TemplateBindings of UserControls

Tags: silverlight, binding, dependency-properties, templatebinding

I have a MainPage.xaml with a TextBox (Binding TextBoxText) and some nested UserControls, which all have a TextBox with a TemplateBinding / Binding too (4 TextBoxes).
I would like have the same text in every box, when I change the text somewhere.

The solution: [Link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/76509861/SilverlightCustomControl%20Vers.9.zip)

What could I do to synchronize all texts?

Thanks!

MainPage.xaml (TextBoxText is the one, which I like to display everywhere)

```
<myContDll:DefaultContainerTemplate Caption="NewCaption">
    <StackPanel x:Name="myStackPanel">
        <sdk:Label Content="Binding TextBoxText of MainPage"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding TextBoxText}"/>
        <myDll:MyButtonControl x:Name="ButtonControl" Count="44"
                           Button3Caption="NewButton3" 
                           Button3Visibility="Visible"  
                           DisplayText="Form2Text2"
                           TextBoxText="{Binding TextBoxText}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</myContDll:DefaultContainerTemplate>
```

Generic.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="local:MyButtonControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyButtonControl">
                <StackPanel>
                    <sdk:Label Content="inner control test"/>
                    <sdk:Label Content="TemplateBinding TextBoxText of MyButtonControl"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding TextBoxText}"/>
                    <Button Content="{TemplateBinding Button3Caption}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding Button3Visibility}" x:Name="Button3"/>
                    <local:CountDisplayControl x:Name="Control1" TextBoxText="{TemplateBinding TextBoxText}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding VisibilityText1}" Count="{TemplateBinding Count}" DisplayText="{TemplateBinding DisplayText1}"/>
                    <local:CountDisplayControl2 x:Name="Control2" TextBoxText="{TemplateBinding TextBoxText}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding VisibilityText2}" Count="{TemplateBinding Count}" DisplayText="{TemplateBinding DisplayText2}"/>
                    <local:CountDisplayUserControl TextBoxText="{TemplateBinding TextBoxText}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="local:CountDisplayControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CountDisplayControl">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <sdk:Label Content="Control1"/>
                        <sdk:Label Content="{TemplateBinding Count}"/>
                        <sdk:Label x:Name="labelText" Content="{TemplateBinding Text}"/>
                        <sdk:Label Content="TemplateBinding TextBoxText of CountDisplayControl"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding TextBoxText}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="local:CountDisplayControl2">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CountDisplayControl2">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <sdk:Label Content="Control2"/>
                        <sdk:Label Content="{TemplateBinding Count}"/>
                        <sdk:Label x:Name="labelText" Content="{TemplateBinding Text}"/>
                        <sdk:Label Content="TemplateBinding TextBoxText of CountDisplayControl2"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding TextBoxText}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your `Binding` `Mode` to `TwoWay` binding:

```
<myContDll:DefaultContainerTemplate Caption="NewCaption">
    <StackPanel x:Name="myStackPanel">
        <sdk:Label Content="Binding TextBoxText of MainPage"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding TextBoxText, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <myDll:MyButtonControl x:Name="ButtonControl" Count="44"
                    Button3Caption="NewButton3" 
                    Button3Visibility="Visible"  
                    DisplayText="Form2Text2"
                    TextBoxText="{Binding TextBoxText, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</myContDll:DefaultContainerTemplate>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks! I tried this and changed (/uploaded) my solution. Unfortunately it doesn't work... I think, I need the Source- definition... But my tests are missed...